# MSBuild fails to run UITest for VS2017 after migrating from VS2015

Tags: unit-testing, msbuild, visual-studio-2017, coded-ui-tests

When running UITest using MSBuild fails to load. However same test project runs successfully via Visual Studio.

Now i have looked everywhere for last 2-3 days people had similiar issue who have tried to the following:

1. Make sure CodedUI Test framework is installed
2. Change the VSToolsVersion to 15.0

I get the following error:

```
UIMap.Designer.cs(585,29): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'UITestControl' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Note:
Migrated from VS2015 to VS2017

EDIT:
Command line for MSBuild:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe"; 
"$(SolutionDir)\VMSCommsUITests\bin\Release\VMSCommsUITests.dll" /settings:"$(SolutionDir)\VMSCommsUITests\VMSCommsUITests.runsettings";
```

We pass in the $SolutionDir via arguments

Comment: Are you use the MSBuild.exe 15.0, which is located at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe`. And what is your build command line?

Comment: Yes we are using MSBuild.exe from directory you specified. I've included the command line for the build above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it seems that I had also installed BuildTools after installing VS2017.

So upon further investigating i found that some dependencies were missing.
As a result i mmade sure the MSBuild from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe` is being used instead and it seemed to resolve the issue for me.